# Instance error Django Test models.py AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute

Tags: django, django-models, instance, django-testing, django-tests

I am performing a Django test case for models.py file the models.py file looks like

```
import sys
from datetime import datetime

from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
from django.apps import apps
from django.conf import settings
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
from django.core.validators import MaxValueValidator, MinValueValidator
from django.db import models
from django.db.models.signals import post_save, post_delete
from django.dispatch import receiver
from django_google_maps import fields as map_fields
from django_mysql.models import ListTextField
from simple_history.models import HistoricalRecords

from farm_management import config
from igrow.utils import get_commodity_name, get_region_name, get_farmer_name, get_variety_name

db_config = settings.USERS_DB_CONNECTION_CONFIG


class Device(models.Model):
    id = models.CharField(max_length=100, primary_key=True)
    fetch_status = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    last_fetched_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    geolocation = map_fields.GeoLocationField(max_length=100)
    device_status = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=config.DEVICE_STATUS, default='new')
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    history = HistoricalRecords()


class Farm(models.Model):
    farmer_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()  # User for which farm is created
    irrigation_type = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=config.IRRIGATION_TYPE_CHOICE)
    soil_test_report = models.CharField(max_length=512, null=True, blank=True)
    water_test_report = models.CharField(max_length=512, null=True, blank=True)
    farm_type = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=config.FARM_TYPE_CHOICE)
    franchise_type = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=config.FRANCHISE_TYPE_CHOICE)
    total_acerage = models.FloatField(help_text="In Acres", null=True, blank=True,
                                      validators=[MaxValueValidator(1000000), MinValueValidator(0)])
    farm_status = models.CharField(max_length=50, default="pipeline", choices=config.FARM_STATUS_CHOICE)
    assignee_id = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True, blank=True)  # Af team user to whom farm is assigned.
    previous_crop_ids = ListTextField(base_field=models.IntegerField(), null=True, blank=True, size=None)
    sr_assignee_id = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    lgd_state_id = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    district_code = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    sub_district_code = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    village_code = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    farm_network_code = models.CharField(max_length=12, null=True, blank=True)
    farm_health = models.IntegerField(validators=[MaxValueValidator(100), MinValueValidator(0.1)],
                                      help_text="In Percentage", null=True, blank=True)
    soil_k = models.FloatField(verbose_name="Soil (K)", null=True, blank=True)
    soil_n = models.FloatField(verbose_name="Soil (N)", null=True, blank=True)
    soil_p = models.FloatField(verbose_name="Soil (P)", null=True, blank=True)
    water_ec = models.FloatField(verbose_name="Water (ec)", null=True, blank=True)
    water_ph = models.FloatField(verbose_name="Water (pH)", null=True, blank=True)
    soil_test_report_date = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    water_test_report_date = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    pest_problems = models.TextField(verbose_name="Pest Problems (If Any)", null=True, blank=True)
    onboarded_by_id = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    farm_image = models.CharField(max_length=512, null=True, blank=True)
    updated_by_id = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    created_by_id = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    device_id = models.ForeignKey(Device, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="farm", null=True, blank=True,
                                  db_column='device_id')
    boundary_coord = models.TextField(verbose_name="Boundary of Farm", null=True, blank=True)
    lat = models.DecimalField(max_digits=22, decimal_places=16, blank=True, null=True)
    lng = models.DecimalField(max_digits=22, decimal_places=16, blank=True, null=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    region_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    farmer_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    farm_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    pending_tasks = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    batch_count = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0, null=True, blank=True)
    locality = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    history = HistoricalRecords()

    class Meta:
        indexes = [
            models.Index(fields=['farmer_id']),
            models.Index(fields=['assignee_id']),
            models.Index(fields=['sr_assignee_id'])
        ]

    def __str__(self):
        return self.farm_name

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.lgd_state_id:
            region_name = get_region_name(self.lgd_state_id)
            if region_name:
                self.region_name = region_name[0]
        if self.farmer_id:
            farmer_name = get_farmer_name(self.farmer_id, 'name')
            if not farmer_name.empty:
                self.farmer_name = farmer_name[0]
                self.farm_name = "{}'s farm".format(self.farmer_name)
                if self.total_acerage:
                    self.farm_name += " - {} acres".format(self.total_acerage)
        super(Farm, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def update_pending_tasks(self):
        BatchSOPManagement = apps.get_model('sop_management', 'BatchSOPManagement')
        self.pending_tasks = BatchSOPManagement.objects.filter(batch_id__farm_id=self.id, current_status=2,
                                                               due_datetime__lt=datetime.today()).count()
        self.save()

    def update_batch_count(self):
        Batch = apps.get_model('farm_management', 'Batch')
        self.batch_count = Batch.objects.filter(farm_id=self.id).count()
        self.save()

    def update_farm_health(self):
        Batch = apps.get_model('farm_management', 'Batch')
        farm_health = [batch.batch_health * batch.acerage for batch in Batch.objects.filter(farm_id=self.id) if
                       batch.acerage and batch.batch_health]
        total_acerage = sum([batch.acerage for batch in Batch.objects.filter(farm_id=self.id) if batch.acerage])
        if total_acerage:
            self.farm_health = sum(farm_health) / total_acerage
            self.save()


class HistoricalCropInfo(models.Model):
    historical_yield_per_acre = models.FloatField(verbose_name="Yield / Acre - Historical")
    commodity_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    commodity_variety_id = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    farm_id = models.ForeignKey(Farm, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="hist_crops", db_column='farm_id')
    history = HistoricalRecords()


class Batch(models.Model):
    commodity_id = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    commodity_variety_id = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    farm_id = models.ForeignKey(Farm, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="batches", null=True, blank=True,
                                db_column='farm_id')
    start_date = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    acerage = models.FloatField(verbose_name='Batch Acerage', help_text="In Acres;To change this value go to farms>crop"
                                , validators=[MaxValueValidator(1000000), MinValueValidator(0.01)])
    batch_health = models.IntegerField(validators=[MaxValueValidator(100), MinValueValidator(0)],
                                       help_text="In Percentage", default=100, null=True, blank=True)
    stage = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=config.STAGE_CHOICES, default='germination', null=True, blank=True)
    expected_delivery_date = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    current_pdd = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
    historic_pdd = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
    current_gdd = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
    historic_gdd = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
    sub_farmer_id = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    batch_status = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=config.BATCH_STATUS, default='to_start')
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_by_id = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    created_by_id = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    historical_yield_per_acre = models.FloatField(verbose_name="Yield / Acre - Historical", null=True, blank=True)
    expected_produce = models.FloatField(default=0, null=True, blank=True)
    actual_produce = models.FloatField(default=0, null=True, blank=True)
    sop_adherence = models.FloatField(default=0, null=True, blank=True)
    actual_yield_per_acre = models.FloatField(default=0, null=True, blank=True)
    end_date = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    commodity_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    batch_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    batch_median_health = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    pending_tasks = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True, blank=True, default=0)
    history = HistoricalRecords()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.batch_name

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        SOPMaster = apps.get_model('sop_management', 'SOPMaster')
        BatchSOPManagement = apps.get_model('sop_management', 'BatchSOPManagement')
        batch_sop_list = []
        if self.batch_status is 'completed':
            self.update_batch_end_date()
        self.commodity_name = self.update_commodity_name()
        self.batch_median_health = self.update_batch_median_health()
        self.batch_name = self.update_batch_name()
        super(Batch, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def update_commodity_name(self):
        if self.commodity_id:
            commodity_name = get_commodity_name(self.commodity_id)
            if commodity_name:
                return commodity_name[0]
        return None

    def update_batch_median_health(self):
        if self.start_date and self.expected_delivery_date:
            start_date = datetime.combine(self.start_date, datetime.min.time())
            expected_delivery_date = datetime.combine(self.expected_delivery_date, datetime.min.time())
            end_date = min([expected_delivery_date, datetime.today()]) - relativedelta(hours=5, minutes=30)
            hours_diff = int((((end_date - start_date).total_seconds()) / 3600 / 2))
            median_date = start_date + relativedelta(hours=hours_diff)
            try:
                median_crop_health = self.history.as_of(median_date).crop_health
            except:
                median_crop_health = self.batch_health
            return median_crop_health
        else:
            return None

    def update_batch_name(self):
        batch_name = "({}) {}".format(self.id, self.commodity_name)
        if self.start_date:
            batch_name += " | {}".format(self.start_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
        return batch_name

    def update_expected_delivery_date(self):
        self.expected_delivery_date = max([batch_yield.expected_delivery_date for batch_yield in
                                           self.batch_yields.all() if batch_yield.expected_delivery_date])
        self.save()

    def update_batch_status(self):
        number_of_yields = self.batch_yields.all().count()
        end_date_list = len([batch_yield for batch_yield in self.batch_yields.all() if
                             batch_yield.end_date and batch_yield.end_date.date() < datetime.today().date()])
        if number_of_yields == end_date_list:
            self.batch_status = 3
            self.save()

    def update_expected_produce(self):
        self.expected_produce += sum([batch_yields.expected_production for batch_yields in self.batch_yields.all()
                                      if not batch_yields.end_date])
        self.save()

    def update_actual_produce(self):
        for batch_yields in self.batch_yields.all():
            produce = 0
            if batch_yields.grade_a_produce:
                produce += batch_yields.grade_a_produce
            if batch_yields.grade_b_produce:
                produce += batch_yields.grade_b_produce
            if batch_yields.grade_c_rejection:
                produce += batch_yields.grade_c_rejection
            self.actual_produce += produce
            self.save()

    def update_sop_adherence(self):
        if self.batch_sop_management.all():
            total_sop = self.batch_sop_management.filter(due_datetime__lte=datetime.today())
            complete_sop = total_sop.filter(current_status=3)
            if total_sop:
                self.sop_adherence = complete_sop.count() / total_sop.count() * 100
                self.save()

    def update_actual_yield_per_acre(self):
        batch_actual_produce = 0
        for batch_yields in self.batch_yields.all():
            actual_produce = 0
            if batch_yields.end_date and batch_yields.end_date.date() <= datetime.today().date():
                if batch_yields.grade_a_produce:
                    actual_produce += batch_yields.grade_a_produce
                if batch_yields.grade_b_produce:
                    actual_produce += batch_yields.grade_b_produce
                if batch_yields.grade_c_rejection:
                    actual_produce += batch_yields.grade_c_rejection
            batch_actual_produce += actual_produce
        if self.acerage and batch_actual_produce:
            self.actual_yield_per_acre = batch_actual_produce / self.acerage
            self.save()

    def update_batch_end_date(self):
        batch_yields = self.batch_yields.order_by('-end_date')
        if batch_yields.exists():
            batch_yields_id = batch_yields.filter(end_date__isnull=False)
            if batch_yields_id.exists():
                self.end_date = batch_yields[0].end_date
            else:
                self.end_date = datetime.now()
        else:
            raise ValidationError("Batch yield end date does not exists")

    def update_pending_tasks(self):
        BatchSOPManagement = apps.get_model('sop_management', 'BatchSOPManagement')
        self.pending_tasks = BatchSOPManagement.objects.filter(batch_id=self.id, current_status=2,
                                                               due_datetime__lt=datetime.today()).count()
        self.save()


class BatchYield(models.Model):
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_by_id = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    created_by_id = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    expected_production = models.FloatField(default=0, validators=[MaxValueValidator(1000000000), MinValueValidator(0)],
                                            null=True, blank=True)
    grade_a_produce = models.FloatField(verbose_name='Grade A - Produce', default=0, null=True, blank=True,
                                        validators=[MaxValueValidator(1000000000), MinValueValidator(0)])
    grade_b_produce = models.FloatField(verbose_name='Grade B - Produce', default=0, null=True, blank=True,
                                        validators=[MaxValueValidator(1000000000), MinValueValidator(0)])
    grade_c_rejection = models.FloatField(verbose_name='Grade C - Rejection', default=0, null=True, blank=True,
                                          validators=[MaxValueValidator(1000000000), MinValueValidator(0)])
    expected_delivery_date = models.DateTimeField()
    batch_id = models.ForeignKey(Batch, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="batch_yields", db_column='batch_id')
    end_date = models.DateTimeField(help_text="Fill this date when this yield is realised with final date", null=True,
                                    blank=True)
    grade_a_sell_price = models.DecimalField(verbose_name='Grade A Sell Price', decimal_places=2, max_digits=7,
                                             null=True, blank=True)
    grade_b_sell_price = models.DecimalField(verbose_name='Grade B Sell Price', decimal_places=2, max_digits=7,
                                             null=True, blank=True)
    expected_grade_a_produce = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=12, null=True, blank=True)
    expected_grade_b_produce = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=12, null=True, blank=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    history = HistoricalRecords()

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(BatchYield, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def update_expected_grade_produce(self):
        batch_median_health = self.batch_id.batch_median_health
        if batch_median_health:
            if batch_median_health == 100:
                grade_a_percentage = 60
                grade_b_percentage = 40
            elif 90 <= batch_median_health < 100:
                grade_a_percentage = 50
                grade_b_percentage = 50
            elif 85 <= batch_median_health < 90:
                grade_a_percentage = 45
                grade_b_percentage = 55
            elif 80 <= batch_median_health < 85:
                grade_a_percentage = 40
                grade_b_percentage = 60
            elif 70 <= batch_median_health < 80:
                grade_a_percentage = 30
                grade_b_percentage = 70
            elif 65 <= batch_median_health < 70:
                grade_a_percentage = 20
                grade_b_percentage = 80
            else:
                grade_a_percentage = 0
                grade_b_percentage = 100
            self.expected_grade_a_produce = grade_a_percentage * self.expected_production / 100
            self.expected_grade_b_produce = grade_b_percentage * self.expected_production / 100
            self.save()


class batchActualProduce(models.Model):
    harvest_date = models.DateField()
    batch_produce = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    grade = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=True, blank=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    batch_id = models.ForeignKey(Batch, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="batch_produce", db_column='batch_id')


class Microbes(models.Model):
    microbe_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    product_code = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    beneficial_organism = models.TextField("beneficial_organism", null=True, blank=True)
    product_nomenclature = models.TextField("product_nomenclature", null=True, blank=True)
    utilization = models.TextField("uti", null=True, blank=True)
    yield_increase = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    savings = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    fk_crop_id = models.IntegerField()
    fk_region_id = models.IntegerField()
    recommended_utilization = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    status = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True, default=True)
    remedy = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    history = HistoricalRecords()

    class Meta:
        db_table = "microbes"

    @property
    def region_name(self):
        """function to return region_name based on lgd_state_id"""
        if self.fk_region_id:
            region_name = get_region_name(self.fk_region_id)
            if region_name:
                return region_name[0]
        return None

    @property
    def commodity_name(self):
        """function to return commodity_name based on commodity_id"""
        if self.fk_crop_id:
            commodity_name = get_commodity_name(self.fk_crop_id)
            if commodity_name:
                return commodity_name[0]
        return None

    @property
    def remedy_name(self):
        """function to return commodity_name based on commodity_id"""
        remedy_name = ""
        if self.remedy:
            remedy_id_list = str(self.remedy).split(",")
            remedy_name = ",".join(x.name for x in OrganismMapping.objects.filter(id__in=remedy_id_list))
        return remedy_name


class MicrobesMapping(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    microbe_id = models.ForeignKey(Microbes, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="microbes_mapping",
                                   db_column='microbe_id')
    zone_com_microbe_id = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    remedy = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    status = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    history = HistoricalRecords()


class OrganismMapping(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.TextField()
    status = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    history = HistoricalRecords()


class CropAttributes(models.Model):
    commodity_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    state_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    variety_id = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    season_id = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    attribute_value = models.FloatField()
    attribute_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    attribute_unit = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    status = models.BooleanField(default=True, null=True, blank=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    @property
    def commodity_name(self):
        """
        function to return commodity_name based on commodity_id
        """
        if self.commodity_id:
            commodity_name = get_commodity_name(self.commodity_id)
            if commodity_name:
                return commodity_name[0]
        return None

    @property
    def state_name(self):
        """
        function to return region_name based on lgd_state_id
        """
        if self.state_id:
            state_name = get_region_name(self.state_id)
            if state_name:
                return state_name[0]
        return None

    @property
    def variety_name(self):
        """
        function to return variety_name based on variety_id
        """
        if self.variety_id:
            variety_name = get_variety_name(self.variety_id)
            if variety_name:
                return variety_name[0]
        return None


class CropAttributesMaster(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    unit = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)


@receiver([post_save, post_delete], sender=BatchYield)
def expected_delivery_date_update(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    try:
        sys.setrecursionlimit(120)
        instance.batch_id.update_expected_delivery_date()
        instance.batch_id.update_batch_status()
        # instance.batch_id.update_expected_produce()
        instance.batch_id.update_actual_produce()
        instance.batch_id.update_sop_adherence()
        instance.batch_id.update_actual_yield_per_acre()
        instance.update_expected_grade_produce()
    except:
        pass


@receiver([post_save, post_delete], sender=Batch)
def update_batch_count(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.farm_id.update_batch_count()


@receiver(post_save, sender=Batch)
def update_farm_health(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.farm_id.update_farm_health()
```

for models.py file first I am testing the Batch class
in test_batch.py file which looks like

```
from datetime import datetime
from django import apps
from django.dispatch import receiver
from django.test import TestCase
from django.db.utils import IntegrityError
from django.db.models.signals import post_save, post_delete
from farm_management.models import Farm, Device, BatchYield, Batch
from sop_management.models import BatchSOPManagement


class TestBatch(TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.batch1 = Batch.objects.create(
            batch_name="(907) Cucumber | 2021-08-21",
            acerage="4",
            commodity_name="Cucumber"
        )

        self.farm_id = Farm.objects.create(farmer_id="106", batch_count="1")

    def test_update_batch_name(self):
        for i in range(5):
            Batch.objects.create(farm_id=self.farm_id, commodity_name="Cucumber")

        self.batch1.update_batch_name()
        assert self.batch1.batch_name == 5

    def test_batch(self):
        self.assertEqual(self.batch1.batch_name, "(907) Cucumber | 2021-08-21")
        self.assertEqual(self.batch1.acerage, "4")
        self.assertEqual(self.farm_id.farmer_id, "106")
        self.assertEqual(self.batch1.commodity_name, "Cucumber")

    def test_return(self):
        batch11 = Batch.objects.create(batch_name="(907) Cucumber | 2021-08-21", acerage="4")
        batch11.save()
        self.assertEqual(str(batch11), "(907) Cucumber | 2021-08-21")

    def test_batch_count(self):
        for i in range(1):
            Batch.objects.create(farm_id=self.farm_id, acerage="4")
            self.batch1.update_batch_count()
            assert self.batch1.batch_count == 1
```

while performing the testing of batch class everytime I am getting the same error
the error looks

```
ERROR: test_update_batch_name (farm_management.test.models.test_batch.TestBatch)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/admin123/igrow-api/app/farm_management/test/models/test_batch.py", line 14, in setUp
    self.batch1 = Batch.objects.create(
  File "/home/admin123/igrow-api/igrow-api-backend/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/admin123/igrow-api/igrow-api-backend/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 453, in create
    obj.save(force_insert=True, using=self.db)
  File "/home/admin123/igrow-api/app/farm_management/models.py", line 179, in save
    super(Batch, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/admin123/igrow-api/igrow-api-backend/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 726, in save
    self.save_base(using=using, force_insert=force_insert,
  File "/home/admin123/igrow-api/igrow-api-backend/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 774, in save_base
    post_save.send(
  File "/home/admin123/igrow-api/igrow-api-backend/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/dispatch/dispatcher.py", line 180, in send
    return [
  File "/home/admin123/igrow-api/igrow-api-backend/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/dispatch/dispatcher.py", line 181, in <listcomp>
    (receiver, receiver(signal=self, sender=sender, **named))
  File "/home/admin123/igrow-api/app/farm_management/models.py", line 482, in update_batch_count
    instance.farm_id.update_batch_count()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'update_batch_count'

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.007s

FAILED (errors=1)
Destroying test database for alias 'default'...
```